# CloudFormation: How to deploy changes with affecting existing resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I want to deploy the changes in the existing stack without affecting any changes to the current roles, security groups, clusters, etc.

How to do that? If I replace the current template, will it affect the current roles, security groups, clusters, etc?

Please help.

As I made the changes and deleted the existing stack and tested new changes, as expected its working fine in dev environment. To deploy the same we don't want to delete the existing stack how can I import new changes?

Answer (score 0):

From [Update behaviors of stack resources - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html):

> When you submit an update, AWS CloudFormation updates resources based on differences between what you submit and the stack's current template. Resources that haven't changed run without disruption during the update process.
>
> The method AWS CloudFormation uses depends on which property you update for a given resource type. Depending on the update behavior, you can decide when to modify resources to reduce the impact of these changes on your application. In particular, you can plan when resources must be replaced during an update. For example, if you update the Port property of an AWS::RDS::DBInstance resource type, AWS CloudFormation replaces the DB instance by creating a new DB instance with the updated port setting and deletes the old DB instance.

Basically, resources will remain as-is unless they have been specifically changed in the template. Some resource types can update in-place, while other resource types require a complete replacement of the resource being changed.

Resources created through a CloudFormation stack, should always be changed by modifying the template and then deploying the change. This way, CloudFormation remains aware of the resources and their configurations. If you change resources *outside* of CloudFormation, it will create 'drift' from what CloudFormation thinks has been deployed.

Comment: Using the example you quote, what if you want to change an RDS instance port but retain everything in the database?

Comment: Which database engine are you using, and is it Amazon Aurora? See:  [AWS::RDS::DBInstance - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html)